# Finding the greatest number of regions on a plane

Tags: geometry

> There are 3 straight lines and two circles on a plane. They divide the plane into regions. Find the greatest possible number of regions.

[image]

This is the best that I could come up with an I don't really know how to get even more regions. Using some mental calculations, I figured that I could edit the picture and make it into 20 regions. However, the answer key gave me 21 as the answer. Is there a way to find out the number of regions on a plane without using a calculator? Is there a formula for it? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I get 21:

[image]

There can be only six regions "at infinity" (as defined by the straight lines).

- 6 "at infinity"
- 2 "local, but outside circles"
- 8 "entirely within red circle"
- 5 "within green circle but not inside red circle"

Comment: Can you explain how you get 21? I understand the part of 'infinity' but where did you get the 21 from? Maybe you can help me number the number of regions?

Answer (score 1):

The number $21$ for a general configuration with maximal number of intersections follows from Euler’s formula. There are $18$ vertices ($3$ from line/line, $12$ from line/circle, $2$ from circle/circle intersections, and $1$ at infinity). There are $37$ edges ($21$ from lines, $16$ from circles). So $18 - 37 + A=2$ and $A=21$.